# How to delete a Shecheduled Apex Batch?

Tags: apex

I'm trying to delete a future scheduled apex batch job and when entering the Id of the job, I receive this error:

```
Line 4, Column: 22
Variable does not exist: 08eA000000Mtp9qIAB
```

This is the apex code I used:

```
for(CronTrigger ct:[SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger]) {
  System.abortJOb(ct.08eA000000Mtp9qIAB);
}
```

I used the CronTrigger Id: 08eA000000Mtp9qIAB
Not sure what i'm doing incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just Id:

```
for(CronTrigger ct:[SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger]) {
  System.abortJob(ct.Id);
}
```

**NOTE:** This would abort all jobs.

If you want to cancel *just* the one, use a normal String:

```
System.abortJob('08eA000000Mtp9qIAB');
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. Good thing mine failed, otherwise, all my scheduled jobs would've been removed.